# How to use java libraries in python processing

Tags: java, python

Im using processing in python mode but I want to use the processing library sound. But I dont know how to import this into my program in python syntax.
In java its like this:
Import processing.sound.*;
Thanks

Comment: Someone already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476968/using-a-java-library-from-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_library(processing.sound)`. I used it with g4p library

Answer (score 0):

Use the `add_library` function:

`add_library("sound")`