# Call java class from a jar file in python easily without another complicated program like Py4j

Tags: java, python, jar

I am trying to call java class from a jar file in python. I've see people talking about programs like Jython, Py4j, Jpype, etc, but I am hoping for an easier way other than spend lots of time to study a new program. I am new to programming. Thanks.

Briefly, here is what I want to accompolish. Say a jar file called 'Converter.jar'. It has a function 'parse' in a class 'Handler'. How can I call the jar file to realize something like Converter.Handler.parse('my file')?

Comment: I don't know enough about Java to offer concrete help, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476968/using-a-java-library-from-python looks highly relevant.

Comment: Python is not designed to interface with Java. You're going to have to use something specially designed for this. Jython runs under Java normally, and so should have a built in way of doing this. Alternatively, Py4j and JPype appear to be libraries designed to allow interface with Java from CPython.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/index.html) for this specific purpose(much easier than you think), below is an example:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<path_to_jar_file>")
import <package>
```

A link which is a relevant reference to topic in hand is - [link](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html).

Comment: This example just registers the jar file to the sys path. Is CPython required for Jython?

Comment: The link has died, an updated link would be nice