# How to access a tar/zip file in Jupyter notebook as a dependency package

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on python notebook. I have a tar file that is a package that I want to access as import statements. What command do I have to enter so that I can do something like this `import com.netflix.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopTables`.

So my path where iceberg package is this: `/home/abc/iceberg-0.2.0.7z` and my Jupyter notebook is on `/home/abc/notebook1`. What should I run on my notebook1 to install dependency and make to available?

So I unzipped the file in the same path and tried this on a notebook but didn't work. Could someone help me out here?

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/abc/spark_work/iceberg-0.2.0')
import com.netflix.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopTables
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to load a Java library in Python.  You can't really do that (well, technically you sort of can: [Using a java library from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476968/using-a-java-library-from-python)).  I suggest using Java instead.

I base this on the fact that https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg has release 0.2.0 and it contains only Java code, plus `com.netflix.iceberg` is a Java naming convention, not a Python one.

See https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg/blob/d9d95f6dcfd6a043f7fed33964d4c64995545208/core/src/main/java/com/netflix/iceberg/hadoop/HadoopTables.java

Comment: Your question is tagged Python and your code in your question is Python. Do you understand that Python is not Java?

Comment: Sorry my comment should be example in python. The link I mentioned has an example in python and not java.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But they have an example in python like this: github.com/Netflix/iceberg/blob/master/examples/…. So I was trying to run that.

Comment: @Atihska: That example code is *not* Python, it is Scala.  See the language declaration at the bottom of this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Netflix/iceberg/master/examples/Convert%20table%20to%20Iceberg.ipynb