# Can we use PROWIDE with python?

Tags: python

I want to parse SWIFT messages using PROWIDE, is there a way to use PROWIDE with python.
I have tried other python libraries but it does not cover all the MTs.
PROWIDE is quite good but is there a python warper that will make my life much easier.

Comment: Is this about Swift (the programming language) or SWIFT (the banking network)? If it's the second one, this probably shouldn't be tagged [tag:swift].

Comment: Prowide appears to be a Java library and you can't easily use it in Python.

Comment: Hi, indeed Prowide is Java libraries. There are a few libraries mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476968/using-a-java-library-from-python that could be used.