# Need help regarding confusion with jython , django and java

Tags: java, python, django, jython

I have few doubts regarding Jython and will be happy if someone can clear those

1. In Django-Jython , can i install normal Django app the same way like `manage.py startproject  testing`. I mean no relation with java, only python django
2. Can i install normal `Java Spring Hibernate` webiste in Jython. I mean no relation with python
3. or Jython is only used if i need to have both python and java combined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're going to use Jython then you should use Jython.

   `jython django-admin.py startproject testing`
2. Spring and Hibernate have nothing to do with Jython.
3. ["Why Jython"](http://wiki.python.org/jython/WhyJython)

Comment: I got 1 and 3 but i am still confused with 2. So u mean jython will only make python available inside jvm . So i can host j2ee , spring sites like normal way . There is no chnage for that. but if i need to use some python in j2ee website , can i use it

Comment: " if i need to use some python in j2ee application" is a separate question.  Search.  It's been asked.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454182/invoke-python-modules-from-java